# Why am I getting this syntax logic error?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, sql-update

I have a basic Windows Forms application that connects and displays databases. I want to update one of the databases using information from two tables,

```sql
    UPDATE account AS a
    SET accrued = (a.accrued + ((p.intrate/365)*balance))
    FROM customer c JOIN product p
    ON p.prodid = a.prodid
    WHERE c.custid = a.custid AND active = 1
```

That works in DB browser

```cs
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connAccount.CreateCommand())
{
    // adds customers details to the database
    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE account AS a SET accrued = (a.accrued + ((p.intrate / 365) * balance)) FROM customer c JOIN product p ON p.prodid = a.prodid WHERE c.custid = a.custid AND active = 1";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Daily Accrued Updated");
}
```

That in my application gives me the error:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
> near "FROM": syntax error'

Comment: Check the version of SQLite that your app uses. Execute `SELECT sqlite_version();` from your app and log the result.

Comment: On dB browser it says 3.33.0

Comment: This is the version of SQLite that dB browser uses. Your app may use a different version.

Comment: ah sorry that is 3.32.1

Comment: This FROM syntax in the UPDATE statement is supported since version 3.33.0: https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from The query can be written with older syntax but you have to mention for the columns `balance` and `active` the tables they belong.

Comment: i just tried changing them too a.balance and a.active but get the same error still

Comment: This is not the problem. The syntax of the UPDATE statement is not valid in your version of SQLite. I will post a query with older syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of the `UPDATE...FROM` statement in your code is not supported for versions of SQLite older than 3.33.0.

You can use older syntax with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE account AS a
SET accrued = a.accrued +
    (SELECT p.intrate/365
    FROM customer c JOIN product p
    ON p.prodid = a.prodid
    WHERE c.custid = a.custid) * a.balance
WHERE a.active = 1
```